# Fibre of a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free sheaf of modules of rank $n$ over some complex manifold $X$.

To $\mathcal{F}$ we can associate a vector bundle call, $\pi: V \to X$.

The fiber of the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathcal{F}(x) := \mathcal{F}_x \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_x} k(x)$ where $k(x)$ is the residue field for some point $x \in X$. Note that this is definitely a vector space over $k(x)$.

Is $\mathcal{F}(x) \cong \pi^{-1}(x)$?

It seems like a basic question but I cannot find a straightforward answer.

Using the correspondence of between locally free sheaves of modules and vector bundles $\pi^{-1}(x) = \mathcal{F}_x / m_x \mathcal{F}_x$. 
We have the following:

$$\mathcal{F}_x / m_x \mathcal{F}_x \cong \mathcal{F}_x \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_x} \mathcal{O}_x/m_x' \mathcal{O}_x \cong \mathcal{F}_x / m'_x \mathcal{F}_x$$.

Then this boils down to show that the maximal ideal's, $m'_x \subset \mathcal{O}_x$, acts on $\mathcal{F}_x$ as $m'_x \mathcal{F}_x= m_x \mathcal{F}_x$

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is correct.

The [Serre-Swan theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Serre-Swan+theorem) gives an equivalence of categories between vector bundles and locally-free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules of finite rank.

Under this equivalence, the pullback of vector bundles corresponds to the pullback of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. In particular, for $x: \bullet \hookrightarrow X$ the inclusion of a point, the pullback functor on vector bundles $$x^*: \mathsf{Vect}(X) \to \mathsf{Vect}(\bullet) \cong k(x)\mathsf{Mod}$$ gives you the fibre of a vector bundle, and the [pullback functor on sheaves of modules over locally ringed spaces](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0094)
$$x^*: \mathcal{O}_X\mathsf{Mod} \to  k(x) \mathsf{Mod}$$
given by $\mathcal{F} \mapsto k(x) \otimes_{x^{-1} \mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{F}$
gives you the fibre of the corresponding sheaf. If $V$ is a vector bundle and $\mathcal{V}$ the corresponding sheaf, then $x^* \mathcal{V}$ agrees with $x^*V$.