# Fibers vs Stalks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In the passage below, in the last paragraph, what is the meaning for the parenthesized bit - "notice we do not say fiber!".

Is what they mean "notice we did not say that the total space $E$ is the union of the fibers" ?

Cause honestly, I have given it some thought and I don't see why they couldn't have said that.

[image]

Comment: A fiber bundle is a particular type of etale map, so fibers are particularly nice stalks but not conversely.  This is more general.

Comment: Huh there must be multiple definitions of fibers over a point because I have seen fibers over a point to be defined as literal pre images, exactly as a stalk is being described as above

Comment: There is, but I don't think the super-general definition of fiber is all that fashionable anymore.  Maybe it depends on the field (alg. topology vs. geometry).  Anyway, clearly in nLab's exposition they want there to be a difference.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense

Comment: This question is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248922/fibre-of-a-sheaf-of-mathcalo-x-modules